# How to limit the file size limit when uploading a file using the Bot Framework and NodeJS?

Tags: bots, botframework

does someone know ho to set a max file size for images/files uploaded on a Dialog on the Microsoft Bot Framework?

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Set the limit where? You could check the size of the uploaded attachment in your dialog and based on that decide what to do. Would that work?

Comment: Thanks Ezequiel for your reply. Well, I was looking for a built-in functionality on the Bot Framework to help me deal with the file size when a customer uploads an image as part of the Dialog. 

The attachment on the dialog message only contains the contentType and the url of the image so it looks like I will have to make a request to download the image and check there what's the size of the image.

Answer (score 0):

not for NodeJs, but for the C# case i have done this

```
using (var http = new HttpClient())
{
var file = (response as AwaitableAttachment).Attachment;
var file_content = await http.GetAsync(file.ContentUrl);
var contentLenghtBytes = file_content.Content.Headers.ContentLength;
var contentLengthMegabytes = (contentLenghtBytes / 1024f) / 1024f;
return result;
}
```

for NodeJs maybe you should use `https.get` method

Comment: @SurajRao Thank you for the tip, i have updated my answer